# How to override create action of django rest framework ModelViewSet to create bulk records?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Demo model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Demo view

```
class ItemViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

Demo input passing using API post request

```
[ {name: 'Book'}, {name: 'PC'}, {name: 'Phone'} ]
```

How to create multiple table records with single post request?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I used to do with Flask, I went through Django documentation and tried to override the create method.

```
class ItemViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        for item in data:
           record = Item(name=item.name)
           record.save()
        return Response(status=200)
```

Comment: it is better to use bulk_create or/and bulk_update here. Also you could use validation via serializer with many=True (because now, your serializer isn't used (just declared)